# How to linearise constraint including summation and min in an optimisation problem?

Tags: optimization, constraints, linearization

I have the following constraint to an optimisation problem:

```
Σ min(wj,0) ≥ −30 for j = 1,...,n
```

How can I linearise it introducing only n new non-binary decision variables?

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(j, min(w(j),0)) >= -30
```

can be linearized with additional continuous variables `y(j)`:

```
y(j) <= w(j)
y(j) <= 0
sum(j, y(j)) >= -30
```

Note that the interpretation of `y(j)` is a bit difficult. It is `y(j) <= min(w(j),0)` and not `y(j) = min(w(j),0)`. As long as the limit of -30 is not reached it may be less than expected. So you probably should not report `y(j)` to the user.

I hope this was not a homework question.